# combining results of two find commands linux

Tags: linux, find

I have a set of configuration backups that are organized like

```
backup/site1/10-11-2019
backup/site1/11-11-2019
backup/site1/12-11-2019

backup/site2/10-11-2019
backup/site2/11-11-2019
backup/site2/12-11-2019

backup/site3/10-11-2019
backup/site3/11-11-2019
backup/site3/12-11-2019
```

I need to list the configuration files that are less than specific size for one particular date for all sites. In a way so that I could combine following two commands from backup directory

```
    find . -type d -name "11-11-2019"
    find . -name "*.cfg" -size +500c
```

Please help me combining these two commands

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
find 11-11-2019 -name "*.cfg" -size +500c
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60849/find-files-in-multiple-folder-names

Can't check if it works right now :(

Comment: It isn't working. I went through the post and tried to figure out the solution in my context before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. It gave me the hint to develop my command which serves my purpose.

```
find . \( -type f -and -path '*/2019-11-11/*' \) -name "*.cfg" -size -50c -print
```